# Как обработать данные пост запроса в динамической форме

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, форма

Как обработать данные пост запроса динамической формы в php и потом передать это mysql.Дело в том что ещё нужно выводить ошибку если человек ввёл в строку имя меньше 3-ё букв, а в строке телефон если данный телефон существует в базе.А так-же остальные поля обязательны к заполнению.Как всё это сделать без динамической формы я знаю,а как в этом плане не могу понять. используеться для вывода ошибки.Мне котя-бы понять как это сделать?

```html
Сама форма

<form name="test" action="" method="post">
    <div class="form-row">
        <div class="col-8">
            <label for="myName"></label>
            <input type="text" name="fio" class="form-control" id="myName" placeholder="ФИО">
            <span class="error"><?php echo $fioErr; ?></span>
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <label for="myFloor"></label>
            <input type="text" name="floor" class="form-control" id="myFloor" placeholder="Пол">
            <span class="error"><?php echo $floorErr; ?></span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="wraper">
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="col-6">
                <label for="myCar"></label>
                <input type="text" name="car" class="form-control" id="myCar" placeholder="Марка автомобиля">
                <span class="error"><?php echo $carlErr; ?></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-6">
                <label for="myCar"></label>
                <input type="text" name="car" class="form-control" id="myCarmodel" placeholder="Модель автомобиля">
                <span class="error"><?php echo $carlErr; ?></span>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="form-row">
            <div class="form-check m-auto">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="parking" id="exampleRadios"
                       value="option1" checked>
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios">
                    На стоянке
                </label>
            </div>
            <div class="form-check m-auto">
                <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="parking" id="exampleRadios"
                       value="option2">
                <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios">
                    Отсутствует
                </label>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="m-3">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-light" name="add" id="add">Добавить авто</button>
        </div>
        <div class="m-3">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-light" name="send">Отправить</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

```js
//создаёт динамическую форму
$(document).ready(function () {
    var i = 1;
    $('#add').click(function () {
        i++;
        $('.wraper').append('<div class="wraperdelete'+i+'">\n' +
            '    <div class="form-row">\n' +
            '        <div class="col-6">\n' +
            '            <label for="myCar"></label>\n' +
            '            <input type="text" name="myCar'+i+'" class="form-control" id="myCar'+i+'" placeholder="Марка автомобиля">\n' +
            '            <span class="error"><?php echo $carlErr; ?></span>\n' +
            '        </div>\n' +
            '        <div class="col-6">\n' +
            '            <label for="myCar"></label>\n' +
            '            <input type="text" name="myCarmodel'+i+'" class="form-control" id="myCarmodel'+i+'" placeholder="Модель автомобиля">\n' +
            '            <span class="error"><?php echo $carlErr; ?></span>\n' +
            '        </div>\n' +
            '    </div>\n' +
            '    <div class="form-row">\n' +
            '        <div class="form-check m-auto">\n' +
            '            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="parking'+i+'" id="exampleRadios'+i+'"\n' +
            '                   value="option1" checked>\n' +
            '            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios'+i+'">\n' +
            '                На стоянке\n' +
            '            </label>\n' +
            '        </div>\n' +
            '        <div class="form-check m-auto">\n' +
            '            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="parking'+i+'" id="exampleRadios'+i+'"\n' +
            '                   value="option2">\n' +
            '            <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios'+i+'">\n' +
            '                Отсутствует\n' +
            '            </label>\n' +
            '        </div>\n' +
            '    </div>\n' +
            '    <div class="m-3">\n' +
            '        <button type="button" class="btn btn-light delete" name="delete'+i+'" id="'+i+'">Удалить авто</button>\n' +
            '    </div>\n' +
            '</div>');
        $(document).on('click', '.delete', function () {
            var button_id = $(this).attr("id");
            $('.wraperdelete'+button_id+'').remove();
        });

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

При добавлении формы на страницу, можно вешать обработчик на кнопку(с помощью регулярок проверять на правильность заполнения) и по ajax отправлять массив данных формы, а на серваке в php его принимать и и например foreach распарсить тут же проверить по базе нужные данные(телефон) и отправить обратно ответ(совпало или нет). На клиенте принять ответ и в случае не совпало с помощью js вывести ошибки